# How to Create Computed Columns in Entity Framework Core database first using MariaDB. Column type is timeonly

Tags: mysql, .net, windows, entity-framework-core, mariadb

```cs
entity.Property(e => e.AppointmentEndTime)
   .HasComputedColumnSql("ADDTIME([appointmentDateTime], [appointmentDuration])");
```

I did like this. But give me syntax error. please help

This is the error I got.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[appointmentDateTime], [appointmentDuration])),

Comment: And what might that error be?

Comment: Could it be that `[` and `]` is a SQL Server escaping of a column name and should be omitted for MariaDB?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[appointmentDateTime], [appointmentDuration])), This is error I got

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should remove the [] characters as MariaDb doesn't support them.